# Set a static View with ViewNavigatorApplication?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have 2 views :

1: MapView

2: SettingsView

When I call

> pushView( SettingsView );

, and after - inside SettingsView :

> this.popView();

the MapViewdata data have been realoaded.

- Is there a way to set a View, which must not reload, after another view is pushed and poped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to be `destructionPolicy="never"` inside the View parameters.